# Google Maps Activity - won't run unless you update Google Play services

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-intent

I am using a **nexus 5x** with an android **lollipop 5.0** Api level 21(google api included) and this error won't run unless you update Google Play services and Failed to start resolution `Intent` on the `Logcat` of android studio
*android studio version 2.3.2*

[image: maps activity]

[image]

Comment: You can update your emulator and install google play service https://medium.com/@dai_shi/installing-google-play-services-on-an-android-studio-emulator-fffceb2c28a1.

Answer (score 0):

Update your  SDKTools (In Android Studio Tools---> android---> SDK Manager)

Add your gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
}
```